# PHP open flash chart 2 error(get rid of it)

Tags: php, error-handling, charts

I am new to this forum and to Open Flash Chart 2. I just installed a chart in one of my website, which works fine. I am getting the chart points dynamically through a URL using file_get_contents in PHP. Everything works fine, but some URLs doesn't has points data so the chart is returning me the JSON error

```
Open Flash Chart

JSON Parse Error [Syntax Error]
Error at character 0, line 1:

0: <br />
```

I know why the error is punched, but I want to get rid of this, instead it should show "Not enough data to map the chart".

Is there any solution for this?

Thank you in advance :D

EDIT:
MY CODE:

```
<?php
include 'oc/php-ofc-library/open-flash-chart.php';
$url = 'http://*****.api3.nextbigsound.com/metrics/artist/'.$_REQUEST['artistId'].'.json';
$file = file_get_contents($url);

$data = json_decode($file);

foreach($data as $Idx => $key){
    if($key->Service->name === 'MySpace'){

        foreach($key->Metric as $Index => $Item){
            $ctr = 1;
            if($Index == "views"){
                foreach($Item as $a => $b){
                    $record[] = $b;
                }
            }

        }

    }

}

$year = array();
$price = array();
$year[] = 'Sun, 12 Feb 2012'; $price[] = 36.7;
$year[] = 'Sun, 13 Feb 2012'; $price[] = 38.7;
$year[] = 'Sun, 14 Feb 2012'; $price[] = 42.8;
$year[] = 'Sun, 15 Feb 2012'; $price[] = 38.2;
$year[] = 'Sun, 16 Feb 2012'; $price[] = 37.8;
$year[] = 'Sun, 17 Feb 2012'; $price[] = 34.7;
$year[] = 'Sun, 18 Feb 2012'; $price[] = 38.4;



$chart = new open_flash_chart();

$chart->set_bg_colour( '#FFFFFF' );

$title = new title( 'MySpace Views' );
$title->set_style( "{font-size: 20px; background:#fff; color: #A2ACBA; text-align: center; width: 300px; border-radius:50px;}" );
$chart->set_title( $title );

$area = new area();
$area->set_colour( '#5B56B6' );
$area->set_values( $record );
$area->set_key( 'Views', 7 );
$chart->add_element( $area );

$x_labels = new x_axis_labels();
$x_labels->set_steps( 1 );
//$x_labels->set_vertical();
$x_labels->set_colour( '#A2ACBA' );
$x_labels->set_labels( $year );

$x = new x_axis();
$x->set_colour( '#A2ACBA' );
$x->set_grid_colour( '#D7E4A3' );
$x->set_offset( false );
$x->set_steps(1);
$x->set_range('0','6');
// Add the X Axis Labels to the X Axis
$x->set_labels( $x_labels );

$chart->set_x_axis( $x );

//
// LOOK:
//
$x_legend = new x_legend( '2012' );
$x_legend->set_style( '{font-size: 20px; color: #778877}' );
$chart->set_x_legend( $x_legend );

//
// remove this when the Y Axis is smarter
//
$y = new y_axis();
$min = min($record);
$max = max($record);
$len = strlen($max);
if($len == '9'){
    $diff = '10000';
}elseif($len == '8'){
    $diff = '1000';
}elseif($len == '7'){
    $diff = '1000';
}elseif($len == '6'){
    $diff = '1000';
}elseif($len == '5'){
    $diff = '1000';
}

$y->set_range( $min, $max, $diff );
$chart->add_y_axis( $y );

echo $chart->toPrettyString();
```

Here is the `print_r($data)`

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [Service] => stdClass Object ( [name] => MySpace [id] => 1 ) [Profile] => stdClass Object ( [url] => http://www.myspace.com/adamgreen1 [id] => 384 ) [Metric] => Array ( ) ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [Service] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Last.fm [id] => 2 ) [Profile] => stdClass Object ( [url] => http://www.last.fm/music/adam+green [id] => 174985 ) [Metric] => stdClass Object ( [plays] => stdClass Object ( [15383] => 10165386 [15384] => 10165386 [15385] => 10165375 [15386] => 10168408 [15387] => 10171611 [15388] => 10174725 [15389] => 10177797 ) [fans] => stdClass Object ( [15383] => 242392 [15384] => 242392 [15385] => 242535 [15386] => 242580 [15387] => 242641 [15388] => 242709 [15389] => 242775 ) [comments] => stdClass Object ( [15383] => 916 [15384] => 916 [15385] => 918 [15386] => 918 [15387] => 918 [15388] => 918 [15389] => 918 ) ) ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [Service] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Wikipedia [id] => 17 ) [Profile] => stdClass Object ( [url] => http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adam_Green_(musician) [id] => 918802 ) [Metric] => Array ( ) ) )
```

Comment: Please include the worrisome code which is generating that JSON. By looking at it your response includes HTML tags which  is unacceptable if only JSON data is expected

Comment: @Jaspreet Chahal please check my question, I have updated it with my PHP code

Comment: Nick can you post result of `print_r($data);` just after this line `$data = json_decode($file);`

Comment: @Jaspreet Chahal I know why the error is coming cause it does not have the actual data which I want to plot, I just don't want to display that error. Then too I have pasted the print_r, just check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that error, it would seem your php script is returning HTML in some cases, instead of json. That's where you have to make the fix. If your Flash stuff is expecting **ONLY**  json strings, then you cannot ever allow anything BUT json strings to be output from the script.

Comment: Post a capture of the json that's causing the error. There's no `<br>` in the sample you posted, so it's most likely from a "working" sample. We need the json from a broken sample.

Answer (score 0):

Run the php that feeds data for html and check for syntax errors